# Obtive um erro ao tentar criar minha matriz. Erro: Warning passing argument 1 of " " from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz

Estou tentando prgramar um código com uma matriz 3x3. Porém estou a um tempo sem mexer em C e precisei revisar este conteúdo. Acredito que a falha do programa seja alguma dúvida referente a ponteiros, já pesquisei na internet e ainda não achei algo que me ajudasse a responder essa pergunta.

O erro ocorre na função: build_matriz. 
Segue a baixo o código.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

 int existe(int valores[],int tamanho,int valor) 
 {
   int i;
   for( i=0;i<tamanho;i++){
     if(valores[i]==valor)
       return 1;
     }
    return 0;
   }

   int sorteio(int sorteados[],int tamanho){
   int numero,i;


   for(i=0;i<tamanho;i++){
    srand(time(NULL));
    numero=(rand()%9);//pega o resto da divisão do numero aleatorio por 9 (um numero menor q 9)
    while(existe(sorteados,i,numero)){
     numero=(rand()%9);
     }
     sorteados[i]=numero;
   }

 }

 void build_matriz( int ** matriz, int linha, int coluna){
int i,j;
int tamanho=9;
int sorteados[tamanho];
sorteio(sorteados,tamanho);
for(i=0;i<linha;i++){
    for(j=0;j<coluna;j++){
        sorteados[i+j]=matriz[i][j];
    }
}
}

 int show_matriz(int ** matriz,int linha, int coluna){
    for(int i=0;i<linha;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<coluna;j++){
       printf("+%d+",matriz[i][j]);
     }
     printf("\n");
    }

  }

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ]){
  int linha=3;
  int coluna=3;
  int mat[linha][coluna];
  build_matriz(mat,linha,coluna);
  show_matriz(mat,linha,coluna);


  }
```

Comment: seria possível colocar o número da linha onde ocorre o erro, para facilitar a análise ?

Comment: Aqui: sorteados[i+j]=matriz[i][j]; não deveria ser sorteados[(i*linha)+j]=matriz[i][j];? Na função existe você pressupõe que todo o array esteja preenchido mas isto não necessariamente é verdade. Coloque srand(time(NULL)); fora do loop, para que seja executado uma única vez.

Comment: Respondendo o zenturix :No meu CodeBlocks a linha é 33 mas isso pode variar de acordo com o espaços entre cada linha, eu não tenho certeza de quantos espaços dei nessa edição da pergunta.

Comment: Respondendo o Anonimo : Pode elaborar mais esse detalhe que você diz " Aqui: sorteados[i+j]=matriz[i][j]; não deveria ser sorteados[(i*linha)+j]=matriz[i][j];? ". Eu não entendi bem essa parte.

Comment: Considerando uma matriz 3x3 com i+j você tem números entre 0 e 4 (já que ambos variam entre 0 e 2), inclusive com duplicatas (0+2 ou 2+0) quando me parece que você quer gerar índices de um array unidimensional entre 0 e 8.

Comment: Sim, consegui corrigir. Querem que poste aqui o resultado ? Já modifiquei todo o trabalho depois que você me deu essa sugestão. Agora estou trabalhando no mesmo programa porém criando um quebra-cabeça de 8(puzzle de 8) para exercitar o conteúdo da minha aula de IA.